# Assign variables from data table results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like:

```
 var table = db.GetTableBySQL($"EXEC usp_User_OldPassword_Check  @UserName = '{txtUserName.Text}'");
```

it returns two values into datatable. So I want to assign that values into two variables so I do:

```
 bool isOldPassword = false;
 var currentEmpGuid = string.Empty;
```

then:

```
 var test = (from DataRow dr in table.Rows
                        select new
                        {
                            isOldPassword = (bool)dr["IsOldPassword"],
                            CurrentEmpGuid = (Guid)dr["EmpGuid"]
                        });
```

Data comes correctly in `table.Rows` but values are not assigned to my variables.  Any one seeing anything wrong? Regards

Comment: You defined a LINQ query to get the values into an anonymous class with properties named `isOldPassword` and `CurrentEmpGuid`. You could execute the query (`.Single()`) and pull out the values, or you could just assign them from `table.Rows[0]` directly..

Comment: You should read a LINQ tutorial. Creating a new anonymous object won't automatically turn those values into other variables values. You haven't executed the query yet either, so you cannot even read the values. You would have to use `var data = test.First()` (for example) and then `isOldPassword = data.isOldPassword;`

Comment: Also, your code looks to be vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use a parameterized query instead of string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 var test = (from DataRow dr in table.Rows
             select new
             {
                  isOldPassword = (bool)dr["IsOldPassword"],
                  CurrentEmpGuid = (Guid)dr["EmpGuid"]
             });
```

Creates a collection of anonymous objects, one for each row of your datatable, each one containing 2 properties: `isOldPassword` and `CurrentEmpGuid`. So if you do for example `test.First.CurrentEmpGuid` or `test.First.IsOldPassword` you'll be accesing the values from your datatable.

But you don't need LINQ for what you want to do; you can just simply do:

```
isOldPassword = (bool)table.Rows[0]["IsOldPassword"],
CurrentEmpGuid = (Guid)table.Rows[0]["EmpGuid"]
```

to assign your variables the values of the first row of your datatable.

This is of course assuming your query always returns one row...